# Service Worker doesn't register

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, webpack, babeljs, service-worker

I've implemented a ReactJS web application, and I've added a service worker to cache resources. My service worker works as expected for caching resources when I run it on chromium 72, but when I run it on chromium 49 in WindowsXP it couldn't register and becomes redundant immediately, and shows service Worker evaluation failed. Does anyone know why this happened and how can I fix this? Is it related to the incompatibility of the browser and service worker?

dependencies:{
"webpack": "^5.64.4",
"workbox-core": "^6.5.3",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
...
}

Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'set' of undefined in service-worker.js
ServiceWorker startup timed out. The worker was in startup phase:Script evaluated.
Timeout when trying to start the service worker.

[script evaluation failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkTf4.png)

I've tried to change the webpack.config to target chrome 49 and es5. In addition, change the
browserslist in package.json couldn't helpful.
After logging, I understand after clientsClaim() line in service-worker.js my I get the error, but I don't know the exact problem with it and what happens behind the scenes that couldn't register.

It has an error in redundant state in service worer:
Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'set' of undefined in service-worker.js
serviceWorker script evaluation failed.

This is my service-worker.js file:

```
import {registerRoute} from "workbox-routing";
import {CacheFirst,StaleWhileRevalidate} from "workbox-strategies";
import { BroadcastUpdatePlugin } from "workbox-broadcast-update";
import { setCacheNameDetails, clientsClaim } from "workbox-core";
import { ExpirationPlugin } from "workbox-expiration";
import { precacheAndRoute, cleanupOutdatedCaches, createHandlerBoundToURL } from "workbox-precaching";
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from "workbox-cacheable-response";
import * as googleAnalytics from "workbox-google-analytics";

setCacheNameDetails({
  googleAnalytics: "googleAnalytics",
  precache: "install-time",
  prefix: "ITM",
  runtime: "run-time",
  suffix: "v1",
});

const maxEntries = 500;
const maxAgeSeconds = 24 * 60 * 60;
const purgeOnQuotaError = true;

clientsClaim();

cleanupOutdatedCaches();


precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST || [], {
  ignoreURLParametersMatching: [/.*/],
  directoryIndex: null,
  cleanUrls: false,
});

googleAnalytics.initialize();

const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp("/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$");
registerRoute(
  ({ request, url }) => {
    if (request.mode !== "navigate") {
      return false;
    }
    if (url.pathname.startsWith("/_")) {
      return false;
    } 
    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    } 
    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/index.html")
);


registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith(".png"), // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: "ITM-images",
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith(".ico"),
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: "ITM-images",
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith(".json"),
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: "ITM-configs",
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries,
        maxAgeSeconds,
        purgeOnQuotaError,
      }),
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [0, 200],
      }),
      new BroadcastUpdatePlugin(),
    ],
  })
);

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

Comment: We don't see your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've just write the error that occurred @Konrad

Comment: Show the code of the service worker

Comment: @Konrad I've added the code of the service-worker.js file.

Comment: It.may be that service workers were not supported yet in that version

Comment: @Konrad But I checked it and "serviceWorker" in navigator is true. This version is supporting the service worker.